# How can I send input without the user seeing it in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, methods

I am designing a smart shopping cart and using blutooth scanner
It sends data like a numbers or texts
How can I make these texts work and interact but invisible to the user?
i do this But it is not practical

```
  private TextWatcher enter = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            //QRsmartCartTvtc

            if(pass.getText().toString().trim().equals("QRsmartCartTvtc")){
             Intent intent = new Intent(log_page.this,Casher.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               }
           }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(pass.getText().toString().trim().equals("QRsmartCartTvtc")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(log_page.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: it isn't clear what you want to do

Comment: In this code, I designed a QR so that the user can access his account through it
But I want the program to take the password and process it directly from the scanner
That is, without "Edittext" appearing to the user
That is, he performs this operation behind the scenes ..
Like when you buy from applepay
The reader is reading your data but not showing it on the screen. It just does an action

Comment: And why do you need the EditText in the first place? After you read the value from the QR just use it.

Comment: Otherwise if, for a reason I don't understand, you really need to store it in an EditText, why don't you set it as hidden? That means `view.visibility = View.GONE`

Comment: Yeah but How can i take the value without EditText ? I'm new in android studio can you help me with it ?